# How do I Import users in the database without re-hashing the password

Tags: 7, users, importing-exporting

I want to import users from one database to another, without changing password.

Suppose the password is saved as $S$DfAoLR.OJWl04tkzgnZeE3TdJHlz6NxBNpArOKhQAewyyHDFDD in the database; I want to save the same value in the database of the other site.

Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Do this :

```
<?php
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . variable_get('password_inc', 'includes/password.inc');
$old_hash = md5('password');
$hash_count_log2 = 11;

$new_hash = user_hash_password($old_hash, $hash_count_log2);

if ($new_hash) {
  // Indicate an updated password.
  $new_hash  = 'U' . $new_hash;
}
?>
```

or you may check [LINK1](https://www.drupal.org/node/1175562) or [LINK2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205605/drupal-6-user-password-import-to-drupal-7)

Or you can directly import the data from one table to another :

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (ID, Name, Password)
  SELECT ID, Name, md5(Password) AS Password
  FROM OldTable
  WHERE ID BETWEEN 100 to 300
```

Check **[LINK](https://www.drupal.org/node/1633646)** once.

Comment: Thank for quick reply, But I don't want to change(hash) the password during import... I have modified the question.

Comment: Check my updated answer, I think that may help you.